# Command line to GitHub: getting grounding

Tags: github, command-line

I'm new to coding and am getting my grounds still.

I'm working on using the command line to upload to GitHub. I know how to check my status, but how do I see the path of where the repository that is being uploaded is based to make sure the path is correct?

Comment: Have you done any research before asking this question?

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the origin of the git repository.

```
git remote -v
```

This will show you the remote origins you have configured. If you have more origins it'll show them all

Comment: FYI those are called “remotes”, not “origins”. The default name is “origin” but you can use whatever name you want.